# How to disable UIButton by clicking another UIButton on same UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

In a cell there are three buttons: Family, Friend, Accept. Initially Accept button is disabled and rest are enabled. What I want to do is when a user clicks on Family- Accept button should be enabled and Friend button should be disabled.

I tried everything.. still trying and searching for solution

```
{    
   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "friendRequestCell") as! friend

   cell.selectionStyle = .none

   cell.accept.addTarget(self, action:  #selector(RequestsViewController.accept) , for: .touchUpInside)
   cell.family.addTarget(self, action: #selector(RequestsViewController.family), for: .touchUpInside)
   cell.friend.addTarget(self, action: #selector(RequestsViewController.friend), for: .touchUpInside)

   return cell
}
```

Comment: This sounds like a good use case for a `UISegmentedControl`.

Comment: create a model to hold button selection and decide other button based on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do that in your `friendRequestCell`. Listen to all the button actions on the `friendRequestCell`, i.e.

```
class FriendRequestCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var accept: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var family: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var friend: UIButton!

    @IBAction func onTapFamily(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.accept.isSelected = sender.isSelected
        sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected
    }

    @IBAction func onTapAccept(_ sender: UIButton) {
        //add your configuration here...
    }

    @IBAction func onTapFriend(_ sender: UIButton) {
        //add your configuration here...
    }
}
```

Connect the `IBOutlets` and `IBActions` in the above code to the `friendRequestCell's` `.xib`.

Comment: answer is correct, but you need to be aware that views in a TableViewCell are reused, and you may see inaccurate data when you scroll your table, unless you save that data (i.e the buttons you selected) and assign it every time in `CellForRow` method.

Comment: @Lirik Ofcourse that is. The code is just for how to solve the problem statement. The whole tableView configuration is not explained here.